# I want creat an navigation with div showing up after hovering the mouse over one the tab but hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css

about this one:

```
.zakladka-1:hover \~ .menu-zakladki-1 {
background-color: #fff;
visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is how it look like:
https://jsfiddle.net/vusxtbyh/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure, but I think you can't access siblings inside of css.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sibling-1">

    </div>
    <div class="sibling-2">

    </div>
</div>
```

So, you can't put en event on `sibling-1` and expect something to happen to `sibling-2`

What you can do is place events on parents and tell the children what to do.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the case above, you can tell the child what to do ie:

```
.parent .child{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.parent:hover .child{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Hope this helped.